# scrollTop = scrollHeight does not work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, scroll

I'm scrolling a chat box as new messages come in, and it works fine in Firefox and Chrome incognito, but not normal Chrome. What could be the reason behind this?

My simple scrolling code:

```
var container = document.querySelector(".dc-messages-container");
container.scrollTop = container.scrollHeight;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script won't work in Chrome unless you set the container style to `overflow: auto`, or `overflow: scroll`. Chrome simply ignores the [element.scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) setter otherwise.

So, your script is fine, styles are missing.

Answer (score 0):

It works in chrome.
Here's a JSFiddle [scrollTop test](https://jsfiddle.net/o66pp34u/)

My Chrome version is 55.0.2883.87

It may not work if the scrollbar doesn't belong to the element on `scrollTop` is being set.

Answer (score 0):

It does work in chrome.

However, because you're specified that it works in Incognito Mode but not Normal Chrome for you, it seems likely you might have an extension installed which is doing something to the web pages that changes expected behaviour.